# Does the order of condition inside if matter?

Tags: c

For example in this code:

```
node* find(node *cur, int id){
    node* p;

    if (cur->id==id) {
      printf("\n%d found at %p\n", id, cur);
      return cur;
    }
    else {
        if (cur->left!=NULL)  p=find(cur->left, id);
        if ((p==NULL) && (cur->right!=NULL)) p=find(cur->right, id);
    }
}
```

The aim of this function is to return the address of the node in a tree which have the id equal to the input id.
In main I have:

```
while (1){
        fscanf(fi, "%d", &id);

        if (id==-2) break;

        fscanf(fi, "%d %d", &left, &right);

        cur=find(root, id);

        printf("%p\n", cur);

        if (cur==NULL) continue;

        printf("%d\n\n", cur->id);

        if (left!=-1) cur->left=makeNode(left);
        if (right!=-1) cur->right=makeNode(right);
    }
```

Notice the part

```
cur=find(root, id);
printf("%p\n", cur);
if (cur==NULL) continue;
printf("%d\n\n", cur->id);
```

If I change:

```
if ((p==NULL) && (cur->right!=NULL))
  p=find(cur->right, id);
```

To:

```
if ((cur->right!=NULL) && (p==NULL))
  p=find(cur->right, id);
```

I'll get the wrong answer, i.e.
With `if ((p==NULL) && (cur->right!=NULL)) p=find(cur->right, id);`, I got:

> 2 found at 0x56552970dcd0
> 0x56552970dcd0
> 2
> 4 found at 0x56552970dcf0
> 0x56552970dcf0
> 4

But with `if ((cur->right!=NULL) && (p==NULL)) p=find(cur->right, id);`, I got

> 2 found at 0x564024e5ccd0
> 0x564024e5ccf0
> 4
> 4 found at 0x564024e5ccf0
> 0x564024e5ccf0
> 4

Can anyone explain to me why this happens? Sorry for the long post and my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and enable all compiler warnings. In `if ((p==NULL)`, `p` might be undefined.

Comment: This code is dodgy for lots of other reasons - you could strip it down (omit all the irrelevant code) to focus on your question.  As it is you get a great deal of distraction comment about the bugs that you are not asking about.  Here for example, p is not assigned unless the `cur->left!=NULL` is true, so the second `if` could be nested, or if not `p` must be initialised.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is uninitialized. Every reference to it here is undefined behaviour.

You should start with `node* p = NULL` to get consistent output.

> Tip: *Always* initialize variables before using them. Whenever you declare something, make a habit of immediately assigning a value. If you declare variables if and when they're used this is rarely a hassle.

Comment: Thanks for your advice sir. However, I added `node* p = NULL` but it still gives me different output as I stated above. This happened when I change the order of condition inside the second if statement. Can you suggest me more about that?

Comment: Like uninitialized variables being a huge problem, not returning a value from a function that has a return value is also a massive issue. You populate `p`. You never use it. **Turn on all compiler warnings**, especially those for missing return values and unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer have already pointed out a bug in your code.

I will address this part:

> Does the order of condition inside if matter?

**Yes, the order matters.** And we often use that fact in our code.

C only evaluates the sub-conditions until it knows the final result.

So consider:

```
if (sub-cond1 && sub-cond2) {...}
```

If `sub-cond1` gives the result FALSE, the result of the whole condition will be FALSE. Therefore `sub-cond2` will never be evaluated.

```
if (sub-cond1 || sub-cond2) {...}
```

If `sub-cond1` gives the result TRUE, the result of the whole condition will be TRUE. Therefore `sub-cond2` will never be evaluated.

One example of actual use:

```
int* p = foo(...);
if (p != NULL && p->data == 42) {...}
```

Now if `foo` return `NULL` the sub-condition `p != NULL` will be FALSE. Consequently, `p->data == 42` will never be evaluated and that's very good as dereferencing a NULL pointer would have crashed the program.

This concept is often call "short circuit"

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate questions here:

1. > Does the order of condition inside if matter?
2. > Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

The answer to 2 is not related to 1.  The erroneous output is due to failure to initialise `p`:

```
node* p = NULL ;
```

With respect to 1, it is worth answering despite it not being the cause of the bug, because it is a more interesting question.

There are a number of things to consider:

- Short-circuit evaluation
- Side-effects
- Expression complexity
- validity of the second expression given the first.

For the expression:

> *<expr_A>* `&&` *<expr_B>*

if *<expr_A>* is `false` then *<expr_B>* is not evaluated (short-circuit evaluation), because the result of whole expression will be `false` regardless of the value of .

If *<expr_B>* has side effects that *must* be evaluated that may be a problem.  If you swapped the expressions *<expr_B>* would *always* be evaluated and the resulting behaviour may differ.  For example:

```
if( x && printf( "%s", s ) > 4 )
```

will print the string `s` only if `x` is true, while:

```
if( printf( "%s", s ) > 4 && x )
```

will print `s` regardless, while teh result of teh condition will be unchanged.

Another thing to consider, is expression complexity.  In your example:

```
if( p == NULL && cur->right != NULL )
```

The right-hand sub expression involves a fetch and de-reference of of `cur`, a member access, then a comparison, while the left-hand side is simply a fetch and compare of `p`.  So you get the best performance advantage from short-circuit evaluation by placing the more complex expression on the right or `&&`.

Finally the issue of validity of right, given the left may occur for example when you are dereferencing a pointer.  For example:

```
if( p != NULL && p->left != NULL )
```

The ordering then is essential, because `p->left` would cause a run-time error if `p` were `NULL`, but short-circuit evaluation ensures it will not be evaluated.

Short-circuit evaluation occurs also for `||` but in that case, the expression is shorted when the left-hand side is `true`.  So in both cases the order of the operands matters.

Comment: Thanks for your extremely detailed answer. I understood the "Does the order of condition inside if matter?" question. About `if( p == NULL && cur->right != NULL )`, I'm aware that cur->right is access to a member, however, cur is always !=NULL so I think the order should not be a problem here, is it?

Comment: cur != NULL is irellavant because the first test was was for p.  My point was not whether the order makes a difference in this case, but whether it makes a difference in general.  In this case, it only makes a difference with respect to the expression complexity _advice_.  Semantically in this case the order does not matter.